# How data saved in memory DOS 16 bit ASM?

Tags: assembly, dos, 16-bit

I am new to ASM. I have question regarding how data saved in memory.

Here is my ASM 16 bit code

```
;db.com
.model small
.code
org 100h
start:
jmp proses
A db '123'
B dw 0abcdh
proses:

int 20h
end start
```

Then I try to debug with `-d` command

[image]

The above picture shown that `A` variable in correct order in hexa value, but `B` variable in `CD` then `AB`.

My question is why data in `A` variable saved differently with `B` variable can you please explain me?

Comment: You are observing what happens because x86 is a little endian system. `A db '123'` simply stores 3 bytes in a row. When you move beyond data elements that are more than one byte in size the bytes are stored in reverse order. `B dw 0abcdh` is a 16-bit value so the bytes of the word are stored in memory in reverse order, so in memory it appears as `cd ab`. If you had `C dd 11223344h` the bytes would be stored in reverse order as `44 33 22 11`

Comment: See [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) in wikipedia.

Comment: The case of an instruction sequence is a little more complicated. It begins with the instruction opcode, and if there is a 16-bit operand, that will be in little-endian order, ie the least significant byte first. Instruction sequences always begin with the opcode (regardless of endianness) otherwise the processor won't know how many bytes comprise the instruction.

Answer (score 1):

x86 is using little endian, so **word** will be stored as *low-byte, high-byte* and **dword** as *low-word, high-word*

`0x1020`     will be `0x20 0x10` in memory
and   `0xabcd1234` will be `0x34 0x12 0xcd 0xab`

by defining `db <string>` you order the assembler to use the string as a sequence of bytes, and each byte is stored in the same order, one by one

so e.g.
`db '012345",13,0` will be `0x30 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x0D 0x00`

Comment: I corrected an error in your answer. You mistakenly wrote __quad__ which isn't the same as __dword__!